# What are these Apple App Store Fonts?

Tags: font-identification, ipad, apple

From this iPad App Store screenshot, what are the fonts for the Title, Author and Description text? Myriad Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [Helvetica Neue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica_Neue#Neue_Helvetica_.281983.29):

[image: Helvetica Neue]

Direct Comparison (see comment...thanks JohnB!):

[image: Comparison]

Comment: You beat me to it, here was my sample analysis (original on the left): http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZNbs.png

Comment: Nice. I'll throw it in.

Comment: Great.  What about size and weights?
Title - Bold 18pt?
Author - Bold 14pt?
Desc - Regular 12pt?

Comment: @B-Money I'd say bold and regular, yes. Maybe light for the description, but I doubt it. I don't entirely know how sizes would work out, though. You might do well just to open a screenshot in whatever image editor you're using and overlay the font. Unless it's retina, then I'm not sure what that would do to the sizing.